# R scatterplot3d: scaling line widths (lwd)

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to build a virtual forest stand in three dimensions. 
For each tree I have x,y coordinates and height (z coordinate) from which I have successfully ploted a forest stand using scatterplot3d.

I would now like to plot each 'tree' width with respect to diameter measurements for each tree.

I have used the lwd function referring to the diameter measurements (see below). This indeed plots lines of different diameters, but they do not refer to the actual diameter of the tree. (some large trees are plotted 'skinny' and some narrow trees are plotted 'large'). It appears to be a sorting issue.

Thankyou in advance for your advice

```
Xc=Tree_Survey5$Xa
Yc=Tree_Survey5$Ya
Zc=Tree_Survey5$TreeHeight
color=Tree_Survey5$color
DBH= Tree_Survey5$DBH / 10


s3d <-  scatterplot3d(x=Xc, y=Yc, z=Zc, type="h", lwd=DBH, pch = " ", color=color, angle = 75, zlab = "Height (m)", xlab = "", ylab = "",main=Title)
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but if you want more flexibility/prettier 3D graphics you might consider the `rgl` package for this project ...

Comment: Some of us have decided not to "play the game" unless the questioner posts a data example coded in R. There is an SO [r] question and answer to be found with search terms: "great reproducible example". It might be as simple as posting the output of `dput(head(Tree_Survey, 20))`.